# what is the meaning of meta in meta Data？

Tags: mysql, database

I have seen class name like *DatabaseMetaData* ,
Meta seems not an abbreviation of one English word.
So what is the meaning of **meta** in **meta Data** ?

Comment: well, that´s quite offtopic as it´s about language, but [Meta is a prefix used in English to indicate a concept which is an abstraction behind another concept, used to complete or add to the latter.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta), so meta data could be understood as the completion to the userdata, or the abstract data resolving the data structure created by the database designer. [Also the Meta-data wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the things with which SO is concerned

Comment: metadata = data about data

Comment: I think that this is on topic... he came across the word meta whist programming and is applying it directly to a programming problem, he has found something whilst using MySQL that he doesn't understand. In fact as you can see there is a clear answer to his question: Metadata in MySQL relates to the data describing the way the records' data is stored.

Comment: Thank u  all above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example: the main goal of a database is to manage records in database tables. But this requires to create a schema where the table will be defined. All the information about the schema is considered to be `MetaData` in contrast to the records contained in database tables.

Another example would be the site [Meta Stack](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). There people discuss how to use and shape the site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) instead of using the site by asking questions and providing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Meta data, when applied to databases, is relating to the table structure (table names, column names, column types, etc...) as opposed to the actual data stored in the database, which is the rows of these tables.